# Is there any NFC message injection?

Tags: injection, nfc

Are there any NDEF message smuggling attacks (like http smuggling attack)?
When I say it, I mean that I have a full control on the NFC packet. Is it possible to inject another packet into a NFC payload or something.

Comment: logic aside, how do you do that physically?

Comment: maybe entring a packet of ndef into the payload?